# Does ammo depletion increase those ammo drops?

Tags: borderlands-2

There are several different types of ammunition (e.g. sniper rifle, launcher, grenades, etc.). I think being very low on a type of ammunition increases the chance that ammunition of that type spawns in the world, such as from piles and ammo chests. Is this true? If so, does the chance increase at a flat rate relative to ammo amount, or is it that, below a certain amount, ammo of that type is more likely to spawn (at a new static chance)?

Comment: I always seem to find more ammo of a type I'm missing. I'm not sure if there is some hidden calculations in the game or not, but it sure seems like it.

Comment: I've always been curious about this as well, and a possible follow up question would be: "if ammo drops aren't random and are calculated by "need", when exactly is what's in a box calculated; does it happen when the level loads, when the player gets within a certain range, or when a player actually opens the box?"

Comment: I don't think so. I've run through my overpowering and had many runs where I get a good amount of pumpgun ammunition (which was nearly full) and haven't get any rockets even if their fully depleted. I think you only notice such a drop of a needed ammunition more than a drop of a ammunition which you don't need.

Comment: I think rockets and grenades are a bit of a special case (ammo regen doesn't effect them) but I've noticed that the lower I am on certain ammo types the more I find as well. I'm sure there is some sort of influence over how much you have to how much you find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get low on a certain ammo type, the game does notice that and acts accordingly. From an [Inside the Box blog post](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1087/inside-the-box-the-borderlands-2-loot-system):

> These are the “need” and “emergency” item pools for ammo. These pools, if they are chosen, have a bit more logic that occurs before the items are dropped. Specifically, the game checks to see if you need the item chosen before dropping it. The rules for allowing the drop are based on how much ammo you have. If you are low you will probably get the “need” but not “emergency” ammo. If you are super low you will probably get two extra ammo drops, one from each of these pools. Health works in a similar way that you are more likely to find health when you are low. There are actually some specific lootables that almost always have health when you are low. Have you figured out which ones?

It's a great article to read anyway. Very in-depth look at how loot is generated. A related tip: if you are really low in something like Sniper ammo and come upon a series of ammo boxes: open all of them before taking any. That way, your low ammo state will be in effect for all the boxes and you'll get more.

Comment: Regarding the question at the end of the quote, if I had to guess from my experience, I'd say garbage bins have the highest chance of containing health.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, ammunition dropped is random. I use a sniper rife for my main weapon, but I usually found ammunition for weapons I do not need.

That said, my sniper rifle never runs out of ammunition. I find ammunition for it when I have about half my capacity left.